# Laravel: The abort() helper ignored in the catch block

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to throw a 404 page if a file that's supposed to be downloaded doesn't exist:

```
try {
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($url);

    if ($fileContents === false) {
         abort(404);
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    abort(404);
}
```

Thing is, that if the file under the specified `$url` is missing, an exception is thrown and the execution lands in the `catch` block - which is fine. However, the `abort(404)` doesn't happen at all. Instead, a blank page is served.

Why is the `abort()` ignored? I can put a `die('foo')` in the `catch` and it will be echoed out.

**Note** - the abort() helper source:

```
function abort($code, $message = '', array $headers = [])
{
    return app()->abort($code, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: you can do " return redirect(route('404'))"

Comment: @moathdev This works if you have a dedicated 404 page with a named route. It's a solution, for sure, but I still would like to know why the `abort()` in the catch block does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and it works as expected. Check if you have any custom 404 error page that's resulting in the blank page or if you have any custom exception handlers set.

```
try {
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($url);

    if ($fileContents === false) {
        throw new \Exception;
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    abort(404);
}
```

Comment: No custom blank 404 page, no custom exception handlers. In your code, the warning/exception will be thrown before it even gets to the `if`.

Comment: I just switched the abort command in the try block to throw an exception instead of a duplicate abort command which made no sense. Try catching the exception in the handler and see if it's being triggered before the rendering.

Comment: The double abort() makes sense. If you check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), you'll notice that there are 3 possible return entities: the read data or FALSE (if the file exists), or a E_WARNING (if the file doesn't exist).